# Getting questions marked as answered

Tags: discussion, accepted-answer, etiquette

There seem to be a bunch of questions posted that have pretty good answers, but the asker hasn't yet accepted any. What is the best way to bump the asker to accept one?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Vote up the answers you think are good. The community consensus is just as important as the checkmark for the OP's "acceptance". Indeed, "accepting" an answer is entirely optional - a question is considered "answered" (for the purpose of statistics and the unanswered page) if it has an answer with a positive score.

Also, if the asker comes back and sees an answer with a lot of votes, they might be more inclined to accept that answer.

Comment: I've been doing that, but I find I keep coming back to the same questions because they haven't been marked as answered. Just wondering if there was a standard way of bumping people to mark an answer.

Comment: I've found it useful (on other SE sites) to comment on the original post, which generates a notofication to the OP.  The comment can say something like "It looks like there are a bunch of good answers to this question - please help other askers find a good answer by accepting one of them."

Comment: Thanks @Benj. I'm new to SE, so wanted to see what proper etiquette was.

Comment: Generally this balances itself out, as if people don't accept answers their acceptance score goes down. When this is low people are often quick to point it out when they ask questions, highlighting that they may not get much help if they're not rewarding good answers.